# Does a Clojure symbol starting with & have special meaning?

Tags: syntax, clojure

I was browsing core.clj in Clojure's source code and came across the definition of [`defn`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L292). The function it defines takes several arguments, the first of which are `&form` and `&env`:

```clj
(def
 defn (fn defn [&form &env name & fdecl]
  ;; ...
  ))
```

**Do these names take on special meaning because they start with `&`?**

I know about rest args and the shorthand anonymous function var `%&`, but this doesn't seem to be either of those things.

I wasn't able to find anything about this syntax in the [Reader reference](https://clojure.org/reference/reader), which doesn't mention `&` explicitly:

> Symbols begin with a non-numeric character and can contain alphanumeric characters and *, +, !, -, _, ', ?, <, > and = (other characters may be allowed eventually).

[Reading Clojure Characters](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters) also doesn't appear to mention this. [`resolve`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve) includes an `&env` arg in its doc string but doesn't elaborate.

Comment: Despite what the Reader Reference says, "&" is already accepted as a character anywhere in a symbol: `(let [&a 1, a&b 2] [&a a&b])  => [1 2]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbols `&form` and `&env` represent special variables used in Clojure macros:  https://clojure.org/reference/macros#_special_variables.

In particular, you may use the `&form` variable to access the line number at which the macro is being evaluated

```
(:line (meta &form))
```

which is useful in printing error messages, etc.

---

Side note on searching for symbol-heavy terms:

**SymbolHound.com** is a search engine that does not elide symbols like Google, so you can often find results there that you can't other places. Searching for `clojure &form` [yields results](http://symbolhound.com/?q=clojure%20%26form).

---

**Update**

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) we see that in the Clojure bootstrapping process, `fn` is a macro making use of `fn*`:

```
(def
 ^{:macro true
   :added "1.0"}
 fn (fn* fn [&form &env & decl] 
         (.withMeta ^clojure.lang.IObj (cons 'fn* decl) 
                    (.meta ^clojure.lang.IMeta &form))))
```

So that is how the compiler injects `&form`, etc.

Comment: The macro in this case being `fn`?

Comment: Right, I get that part. :) But this isn't a normal `defmacro`, so I'm wondering what macro we're _inside of_ at this point. Is `def` itself a macro under the hood?

Comment: @acobster [`def`](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#def) is a special form.